# Is that possible to schedule DaemonSet with podAffinity?

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to schedule the DaemonSet on specific Nodes where some particular Pod/Service are located. My thoughts are I can label the specific label 'app.type=with-aemon' on the Pods, then I can specify the PodAffinity in daemoSet as below:

```
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app.type
                operator: In
                values:
                - with-daemon
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

I do see the DaemonSet Pod is running in the specific node, but I also see k8s try to schedule  DaemonSet Pods in all other nodes, so these Pod status are always Pending.

Does k8s support to schedule DaemonSet with podAffinity? Is my above usage a common usage?

Comment: Depending on the scenario I'd rather use a  Deployment and combine a podAffinity and a podAntiAffinity.

Comment: Even though this question is almost a month old I'd like to ask for a clarification of your requirements. In your very first sentence you mentioned that the additional app should run on the same node as a pod with a specific label. Right now I would assume that multiple pods with the same label could run on the same node and the additional app should run only once on that node, correct? And is it necessary to remove the additional app from the node if all workloads with the required label are removed from the node? Because if it is neither a DaemonSet nor a Deployment alone are enough.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, Daemon set default behaviour is to schedule on all Nodes available except there is Taint set.

i am using **taint + node affinity** to schedule POD on specific node types but would be better to use **Deployment** in that case instead of using the **Daemonset**.

It's on your use case you can use **Pod affinity**, or **Anti-affinity** if want specific **POD** to run with Specific types of **PODs**.

**For example** : you want to spread out PODs across nodes and run on nodes that have **GPU** attached in that case you can use multiple options of **Node Affinity + taints + POD anti-affinity**.

But using **Daemonset** would be a bad idea, unless you have a requirement to run on all available Nodes or new joining during scaling up or so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectors on nodes. But you can't use selectors on pods.

Using `nodeSelector`:

```
kind: DaemonSet
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux # or whatever
```

Using `nodeAffinity`:

```
kind: DaemonSet
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
              - matchExpressions:
                  - key: kubernetes.io/os
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - linux
```

Using a podAffinity like this won't really work though, a pod will be created on each node, even though most will stay Pending until a matching pod runs on that node (and then it will keep running there even if that matching pod goes away):

```
# does NOT work
kind: DaemonSet
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
              - matchExpressions:
                  - key: k8s-app
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - some-app
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

See [this section of the DaemonSet documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/#running-pods-on-select-nodes).

Another approach might be to run your DaemonSet on a specific subset of nodes (using nodeSelector or nodeAffinity like above) and then run your other service on those nodes. All workload types can select a subset of nodes based on labels. You can also put the podAffinity towards your DaemonSet rather than the other way around.

Answer (score -1):

A DaemonSet, by its very nature is scheduled onto every node (except for where there's a taint, in which case you'd need to have a toleration to override that)

If you want these pods to be on specific nodes, a DaemonSet is not the right resource to use, you'd want a Deployment or a StatefulSet.